# What's the difference between :Args and :CaptureArgs in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I can usually get the behavior I desire by just randomly trying different permutations of these two options, but I still can't say I know precisely what they do. Is there a concrete example that demonstrates the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:CaptureArgs(N)` matches if there are at least N args left. It is used for non-terminal Chained handlers.

`:Args(N)` only matches if there are exactly N args left.

For example,

```
sub catalog : Chained : CaptureArgs(1) {
    my ( $self, $c, $arg ) = @_;
    ...
}

sub item : Chained('catalog') : Args(2) {
    my ( $self, $c, $arg1, $arg2 ) = @_;
    ...
}
```

matches

```
/catalog/*/item/*/*
```

Answer (score 5):

`CaptureArgs` is used in Chained methods in Catalyst.

`Args` marks the end of chained method.

For ex:

```
sub base_method : Chained('/') :PathPart("account")  :CaptureArgs(0)
{

}
sub after_base : Chained('base_method') :PathPart("org") :CaptureArgs(2)
{

}
sub base_end : Chained('after_base') :PathPart("edit")  :Args(1)
{

}
```

Above chained methods match `/account/org/*/*/edit/*`.

Here `base_end` is end method of chain.To mark end of chained action `Args` is used.If `CaptureArgs` is used that means chain is still going on.

`Args` is also used in other methods of catalyst for specifying arguments to method.

Also from cpan [Catalyst::DispatchType::Chained](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90012/lib/Catalyst/DispatchType/Chained.pm#Introduction):

```
The endpoint of the chain specifies how many arguments it
 gets through the Args attribute. :Args(0) would be none at all,
 :Args without an integer would be unlimited. The path parts that 
aren't endpoints are using CaptureArgs to specify how many parameters
 they expect to receive.
```